# MERGE, UPDATE, INSERT T-SQL Cannot INSERT value NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, null

Goal: Keep a running table of student class ranks each month of the year

Haves: I have code that provides me with columns

```
StudentID; '+@DateTXT+'
```

The DateTXT is dynamic variable, returns whatever month I'm running the code in.

Needs: I'm trying to use the MERGE, UPDATE, INSERT functions to where I can run the code once and establish a table:

```
| StudentID | Jan |
|  56789    |  2  |
|  12345    |  7  |
```

Then each month I add a new month column the permanent table:

```
EXEC('ALTER TABLE StudentRanking
     ADD ' + @DateTXT + ' smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT(999)')

| StudentID | Jan | Feb |
|  56789    |  2  | 999 |
|  12345    |  7  | 999 |
```

I'll run the ranking code again for February and save it into a temporary table, which I will use to merge, update, insert with the StudentRanking table:

```
| StudentID | Feb |
|  56789    |  3  |

(note.. student 12345 doesn't come up)
```

So I'd like to end up with a running list:

```
EXEC('
  MERGE StudentRanking AS TARGET
  USING ##TEMPDB2 AS SOURCE ON (TARGET.StudentID = SOURCE.StudentID)

  WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.' + @DateTXT + ' <> SOURCE.' + @DateTXT + '
  THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.' + @DateTXT + ' = SOURCE.' + @DateTXT + '

  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (StudentID, ' + @Rank_TXT + ')
  VALUES (SOURCE.StudentID, SOURCE.' + @Rank_TXT + ') ')

| StudentID | Jan | Feb |
|  56789    |  2  |  3  |
|  12345    |  7  |null |
```

Problem: Some students leave the school, thereby creating a null ranking in proceeding months (e.g. 12345 has no rank in February), so when I try to INSERT the results from a temporary table, I get this ERROR:

```
SQL Server Database Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Feb', table 'tempdb.dbo.##TEMPDB'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

I could do an ISNULL(ranking,0) but I'd rather have nulls than 0's

Comment: I notice you are using global temp tables. These can be very problematic with concurrency. The reason you are getting that error is because your table definition for the column does not allow NULL.

Comment: This solution is horrible. Why not just use a properly normalised table where `StudentID` and `Month` make up your primary key? Dynamically adding columns to a table every month, then using dynamic SQL to update it is a recipe for disaster. Are you open to adopting a different approach?

Comment: Always open for to learn a different approach @GarethD
I did get it working, but if you have a source for a better solution, please send if you'd like.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your ALTER TABLE to:

```
EXEC('ALTER TABLE StudentRanking
     ADD ' + @DateTXT + ' smallint NULL')
```

Assuming the down votes are because I didn't offer an alternative that was normalized, I'd recommend using PIVOT for this type of problem.

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StudentRanking 
(
        MonthID CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
        StudentID INT NOT NULL,
        Score INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StudentRanking__StudentID_Date PRIMARY KEY(MonthID, StudentID),
);

INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JAN', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('FEB', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('MAR', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('APR', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('MAY', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JUN', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JUL', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('AUG', 56321, 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('SEP', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('OCT', 56321, 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('NOV', 56321, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('DEC', 56321, 2)

INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JAN', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('FEB', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('MAR', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('APR', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('MAY', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JUN', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JUL', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('AUG', 56821, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('SEP', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('OCT', 56821, 2)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('NOV', 56821, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('DEC', 56821, 1)

INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JAN', 56021, 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('FEB', 56021, 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('MAR', 56021, 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('APR', 56021, 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('MAY', 56021, 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JUN', 56021, 4)
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentRanking VALUES ('JUL', 56021, 5)
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM StudentRanking
PIVOT (SUM(Score) FOR MonthID IN (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, 
MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC)) AS PVT
```

Results

[image: Query Output]

The SUM(SCORE) is harmless in this instance since there is never more than one record per student per month.  It's just there to allow PIVOT to know what to work around.

Comment: Your solution works very well, I think the pivot option is more elegant than using the CASE statements. Both solutions far simpler than my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Always open for a different, better, approach @GarethD!

I actually got it to work by doing:

```
EXEC('ALTER TABLE StudentRanking
ADD ' + @Date_TXT + ' smallint DEFAULT(null)')

WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.' + @Date_TXT + ' IS NULL
THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.' + @Date_TXT + ' = SOURCE.' + @Date_TXT + '
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix is make the column not nullable. It is worth pointing out though that this solution does not scale well. A more scalable approach would be to use a properly normalised table where `StudentID` and `Month` make up your primary key.

You then have something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StudentRanking 
(
        Date DATE NOT NULL,
        StudentID INT NOT NULL,
        Score INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StudentRanking__StudentID_Date PRIMARY KEY(Date, StudentID),
);
```

You can then create a view on top of this to get the table in the format you wanted:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.StudentRankingByYear
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  StudentID,
            Year = DATEPART(YEAR, Date),
            Jan = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 1 THEN Score END),
            Feb = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 2 THEN Score END),
            Mar = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 3 THEN Score END),
            Apr = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 4 THEN Score END),
            May = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 5 THEN Score END),
            Jun = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 6 THEN Score END),
            Jul = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 7 THEN Score END),
            Aug = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 8 THEN Score END),
            Sep = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 9 THEN Score END),
            Oct = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 10 THEN Score END),
            Nov = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 11 THEN Score END),
            Dec = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 12 THEN Score END)
    FROM    dbo.StudentRanking
    GROUP BY StudentID, DATEPART(YEAR, Date);
GO
```

You can even create an indexed view on top of this to get the table in the format you wanted (if you really needed to, but the query should perform well enough without the need for a view), the only difference is you cannot have null columns, so the missing months would have to show as 0:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.StudentRankingByYear
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  StudentID,
            Year = DATEPART(YEAR, Date),
            Jan = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 1 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Feb = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 2 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Mar = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 3 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Apr = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 4 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            May = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 5 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Jun = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 6 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Jul = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 7 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Aug = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 8 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Sep = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 9 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Oct = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 10 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Nov = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 11 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Dec = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date) = 12 THEN Score ELSE 0 END),
            Records = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM    dbo.StudentRanking
    GROUP BY StudentID, DATEPART(YEAR, Date);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_StudentRankingByYear__StudentID_Year
    ON dbo.StudentRankingByYear (StudentID, Year);
```

Comment: Thanks GarethD, both solutions work well. Thanks for providing an option that allows nulls and zero values. Thanks a ton!